# Shared authentication across FreeBSD Jails

Tags: freebsd, jail, bsd

I am using FreeBSD with ZFS to run several jails. For jail management I'm using `ezjail`, and I have a template jail which I use for provisioning.

I want to share passwd, groups, and authentication information across all jails and the host. For the jails it can be read-only.

Is there some mechanism which can share the host passwd, groups, etc. without any complex system such as LDAP/NIS/etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDAP or NIS is the Right Solution -- it's really not that complicated, and you should take a day and learn both (figure about half a day each to get the basics. Less if you buy the O'Reilly [NIS book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925106.do) & [LDAP book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565924918.do).
The big advantage here is you can centralize *some* accounts (administrative access/support users), authorize others on a per-jail basis, and still have local users on specific machines.

---

If you're really dead-set against LDAP or NIS the next best thing is to use Puppet, Chef, radmind, or similar to update the `passwd` and `group` files -- you can automatically synchronize the authentication/authorization files as part of a site-wide deployment process.
Automatic deployment tools have their own complexity issues, but also bring a number of benefits which may make them appropriate for your environment

---

The next step down is a cron job on the host system that copies standard `passwd` and `group` files to each jail at a set time.  This is the simplest solution and works very well, though it is only a very small step up from copying the files yourself manually.

Comment: I know LDAP & NIS, but I simply would rather avoid it. `radmind` seems good, I was considering `rdist` aswell. But I thought there would exist a self-contained solution.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to avoid both of the standard, well-tested, generally-accepted-as-best-practice solutions?

Comment: Thanks @voretaq7, I just wanted a simplistic solution, I think I'll settle on cronjobs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try hardlinks (`ln(1)`).

Comment: These jails are using ZFS, and so hard links do not cross filesystems.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember right, then ezjail sets up a lot of directories and files in the default jail, that are shared across the other jails. I guess you could put users in there too. Maybe it's a bit of analysis first and manual work then.

But to be honest, I think this ruins your jails security. I normally create a jail to isolate as much as possible.

Comment: This would provision the initial users and groups, but would not keep them synchronized.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I missed that point. One more reason to not do it at all (from a security perspective)